# Запуск приложения как службу в Windows. FAILED 1053

Tags: c#, .net, windows-service, .net-6

Собрал приложение, руководствуясь [данным туториалом](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service). Запускается и все хорошо работает.

Перенес приложение на сервер. Поскольку я собирал приложение через `Publish` в Visual Studio с указанием, что хочу иметь один файл, поэтому я переношу три файла `.exe`, `.pdb`, `settings.json`.

Через `sc`, как указано в руководстве создаю службу

```
.\sc.exe create "service1" binpath="C:\path\to\publish\service.exe"
```

И запускаю на сервере

```
.\sc.exe start "service1"
```

Получаю ошибку

```
[SC] StartService FAILED 1053: 

The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion. windows server
```

Понятное дело, поискал и вот, что перепробовал:

1. Манипуляции с `ServicesPipeTimeout`-ключом в регистре
2. Проверены версии `.NET` и `Runtime` с ними
3. Обновление системы

Дайте подсказку, как отловить то, что мешает запуску?

Приложение для `.NET 6.0`, C#, Windows Server 2019

Program.cs

```cs
using CsvToDdWorker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog;

using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService(options =>
    {
        options.ServiceName = "service1";
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        LoggerProviderOptions.RegisterProviderOptions<
            EventLogSettings, EventLogLoggerProvider>(services);

        services.AddSingleton<SendToDbService>();
        services.AddHostedService<WindowsBackgroundService>();
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
    {
        logging.AddConfiguration(
            context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

WindowsBackgroundService.cs

```cs
namespace CsvToDdWorker
{
    public class WindowsBackgroundService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly SendToDbService _sendService;
        private readonly ILogger<WindowsBackgroundService> _logger;

        public WindowsBackgroundService(
            SendToDbService sendService,
            ILogger<WindowsBackgroundService> logger) =>
            (_sendService, _logger) = (sendService, logger);

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            try
            {
                while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    _sendService.SendToDb(_logger);
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20), stoppingToken);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "{Message}", ex.Message);
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD**

Попробовал так же поиграться с периодом запуска приложения. Изменял на секунды, минуту, час. Дело не в этом.

**UPD1**

Запустил исполнение на сервере без службы функцию `SendToDb(_logger)`. на прямую через `dotnet run`. Она работает без проблем.

Comment: .pdb - это сведения для отладки, он не нужен для работы приложения. Ну и код сервиса вы не показали, а проблема наиболее вероятно, в нем.

Comment: Ну не совсем не нужен, с pdb будет информация на какой строке произошёл exception, если они логируются

Comment: @aepot добавил, код не сильно отличается от того, что в руководстве.

Comment: Решил проблему, напишите ответ, кто в теме. Я пересобрал воркер указав в `Publish`-рутине в окне всех настроек `Deployment mode` -> `Self-contained`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле ошибка, которая указана в вопросе очень широкая. Описание, которое прилагается к исключению совсем не несет никакого смысла, вот это

```
[SC] StartService FAILED 1053: 

The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion. windows server
```

Что удалось выяснить:

1. Моя проблема заключалась в невнимательности при следовании инструкции. В `Publish`-рутине в окне всех настроек `Deployment mode` -> `Self-contained` забыл указать.
2. Ошибки, исключения в самой логике приложения никак не влияют на появление данной проблемы. Я инсценировал проблемы, собирал и запускал. Да, приложение крашится, но не в момент запуска службы, а в момент исполнения. И совсем другие коды ошибок.